# Spacebrew (locally) + Arduino Yun + web page - "subscriber" not working

Tags: node.js, websocket, arduino

I need a bit of help with my Spacebrew set up.
I have a small app running on Arduino Yun that sends data from input device to Spacebrew server running on my laptop within the same network. Then I have a simple html+js webpage on the same laptop that is connected to the Spacebrew server as a subscriber. For some reason I cannot "read" any of incoming data via web app - subscriber fails.
I have done a lot of debugging (whole day) and yet I cannot track the error, but I am sure it's related to Spacebrew set up on my machine (or any other depending module).

Here is my debug, info and conclusions:

- Running the same app connected to public Spacebrew server works fine
  (sandbox.spacebrew.cc), so that means my arduino code and html+js is
  correct.
- When switching both to talk to my local Spacebrew set up, the
  subscriber seems to fail for some reason.
- I have an admin page like this one locally
  (http://spacebrew.github.io/spacebrew/admin/admin.html?server=sandbox.spacebrew.cc),
  I can see my client and subscriber on it, I can connect them both
  with "lines" so they should talk to each other (see screenshot
  attached).
- My client (Arduino Yun) sends data every second and the "dot" on
  admin screen blinks every second.
- My subscriber (html+js) stops after the "onOpen" command, but when
  connected to sandbox.spacebrew.cc it goes further to "onRangeMessage"
  (see html+js code attached)
- When running Spacebrew locally with -l param (debug) I don't see any
  errors, everything seems to be fine (see attached console response)
- To install Spacebrew locally I have used npm, I have also installed
  dependencies like forever-monitor and ws, I followed steps from this
  page: https://github.com/Spacebrew/spacebrew
- my node version is v0.10.6
- my system is Mac OS X 10.6.8
- I also have Apache running on the same machine and few other servers (imap, ldap, mysql, ...) but I doubt that could be an issue as I run Spacebrew at port 9000

### **Attachements:**

*JS Code:*

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sb-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var sb = new Spacebrew.Client( '10.5.203.66', 'lokers-photoresistor', 'description', {'port':9000, 'debug':1, 'reconnect':1} );
    sb.addSubscribe( 'brightness', 'range' );

    sb.onStringMessage = function onString( name, value ) {
        console.log('onStringMessage');
        console.log(name);
        console.log(value);
        console.log('-------------------');
    };
    sb.onRangeMessage = function onRange( name, value ) {
        console.log('onRangeMessage');
        console.log(name);
        console.log(value);
        console.log('-------------------');
    };
    sb.onBooleanMessage = function onBoolean( name, value ) {
        console.log('onBooleanMessage');
        console.log(name);
        console.log(value);
        console.log('-------------------');
    };
    sb.onCustomMessage = function onBoolean( name, value, type ) {
        console.log('onCustomMessage');
        console.log(name);
        console.log(value);
        console.log(type);
        console.log('-------------------');
    };
    sb.onOpen = function onOpen() {
        console.log('onOpen');
        console.log('-------------------');
    };
    sb.onClose = function onClose() {
        console.log('onClose');
        console.log('-------------------');
    };

    sb.connect();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

*Spacebrew debug:*

```
info: [pingAllClients] setting validated = false
info: [pingAllClients] setting validated = false
info: [pingAllClients] setting validated = false
info: [wss.onmessage] new message received {"message": {"value": "155", "type": "range", "name": "brightness", "clientName": "lokers-photoresistor-check"}}
info: [handleMessageMessage] message sent to: 'lokers-photoresistor' msg: {"message":{"name":"brightness","type":"range","value":"155","clientName":"lokers-photoresistor"}}
info: [handleMessageMessage] message sent to: 'lokers-photoresistor-graph' msg: {"message":{"name":"line1","type":"range","value":"155","clientName":"lokers-photoresistor-graph"}}
info: [receivedMessage] received new message from spacebrew server: 
info: {"message":{"value":"155","type":"range","name":"brightness","clientName":"lokers-photoresistor-check","remoteAddress":"10.5.228.249"}}
```

*Spacebrew admin screenshot:*

[image]

Comment: after more debug, when running spacebrew with debug
"node node_server_forever.js --loglevel debug". I see this message:
"warn: [pingAllClients] CAN'T PING CLIENT, CONNECTION ALREADY CLOSED"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was bug in latest release, for those experiencing the same issue, please update to latest version of spacebrew.js where this bug was fixed. More info here about bug tracking here:
https://github.com/Spacebrew/spacebrew.js/pull/10#issuecomment-38280949

Answer (score 0):

I started a thread on the Spacebrew Google Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spacebrew-cc/uxzPQFqFN-4). I am having similar problems with the subscriber on an EC2 install. A followup post references the same problem on a beagle bone black server. No solution yet, but same behavior on 3 different platforms.